# What could be causing the light in my basement to heat up and turn off?

Tags: wiring, lighting

I have installed 8 lights in the basement.   It is pretty straight forward parallel wiring into each junction box.  the last one of the 8 just ends, obviously, as no other light is needed so no wires come out of that junction.

Now,  they all work great and turn on but the last one in the bunch is getting hot and turns off (dim) after about 30 seconds... then after about 10 seconds lights again.  and so on.

Should I be looking for something specific or maybe that light is defective?

They are [LED downlights from Lithonia Lighting](http://www.lithonia.com/commercial/led+versi+lite.html#.U-qnf_ldXmt).

Comment: I'd suggest contacting the manufacturer, if they're relatively new. They might say "oops, we've seen that before" and offer to send a replacement... and at worst, you'll be helping them improve the product and/or instructions.

Answer (score 1):

First check the Bulb as it is the easiest thing to check.  Next would to verify the wiring to the fixture.  And last, check the fixture itself.  Since it looks like what you have is a fixture/bulb, you might need to move it to another location and see if it exhibits the same behavior.